# Python Buffer of PNG Image

Tags: python, binary, png, decode

I'm working with the [Indigo library](http://ggasoftware.com/opensource/indigo) for a web based chemistry project. Long story short, they wrote a nice Python interface for it, which I'm using through CGI. There are several output formats, SVG and PNG being included. I'm not a Python pro, so I'm getting a little stumped on the author's idea of a buffer. The following works:

```
#!python
from indigo import *
from indigo_renderer import *
from struct import *
print "Content-type: image/svg+xml"
print

indigo = Indigo()
renderer = IndigoRenderer(indigo);

mol1 = indigo.loadMolecule("ONc1cccc1");

indigo.setOption("render-output-format", "svg");
indigo.setOption("render-highlight-color-enabled", "true");

image = renderer.renderToBuffer(mol1);
output = image.tostring()
print output
```

That is, the above code spits out properly formatted SVG XML with no unwanted leading or tailing characters. Firefox recognized the content type and rendered it fine.

However, I'm having a hard time understanding what I'm supposed to do for PNG:

I change the code to:

```
from indigo import *
from indigo_renderer import *
from struct import *

print "Content-type: image/png"
print

indigo = Indigo()
renderer = IndigoRenderer(indigo);

mol1 = indigo.loadMolecule("ONc1cccc1");

indigo.setOption("render-output-format", "png");
indigo.setOption("render-highlight-color-enabled", "true");

image = renderer.renderToBuffer(mol1);
output = image
print output
```

and I get this (which isn't what I was expecting for a PNG):

```
array('c', '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00[ truncated by me ]')
```

If I try the toString() method, I do get a nice blob of binary (I didn't spend any effort attempting to interpret it), but it's still apparently broken. I have a feeling this needs to be decoded prior to being dumped to the client (I used to do it with PHP) - which is probably rather simple, but I couldn't find much help from the documentation (or perhaps I found what I was looking for and it was beyond my comprehension). I'm just not sure what's going on, and would appreciate some advice.

Comment: what makes you think it's wrong? PNG is a binary compressed format, so don't expect anything else that meaningless bytes. SVG being text it's not the same story

Comment: I'm aware that SVG is a totally different situation - the fact that it worked was simply validation of the rest of the code. And yes, I was expecting meaningless bytes - that's a good thing. However, all image viewers I have consider it broken. Certainly the quoted code "array('c', '\....')" is not correct. Perhaps I should upload my binary output to my server so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Apologies for putting this in the comments as well as here). Solve the problem - Windows sure made this a pain, but for now it will have to do. Unfortunately the code will have to change when I start finalizing it for my Linux VPS, but here's what I did. The output is a character array, and tostring() works as expected, just dumping the raw contents. All I need to do is force the output to write as binary to prevent corruption. To write to a file in binary is trivial, but to write to stdout as binary is platform specific. See: link Thanks for the help. I found the guidance here:

[Win32 Binary Write](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65443-sending-binary-data-to-stdout-under-windows/)
Final code was:

```
#!python
from indigo import *
from indigo_renderer import *
from array import *
import sys, cgitb, cgi

cgitb.enable()
httpArgs = cgi.FieldStorage()
print "Content-type: image/png"
print

indigo = Indigo()
renderer = IndigoRenderer(indigo)

mol1 = indigo.loadMolecule("ONc1cccc1")

indigo.setOption("render-output-format", "png")
indigo.setOption("render-highlight-color-enabled", "true")

outputStream = renderer.renderToBuffer(mol1)
if sys.platform == "win32":
   import os, msvcrt
   msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
else:
sys.exit()
sys.stdout.write(outputStream.tostring())
```

Answer (score 1):

According to what your output is, it is a PNG file. Just save it to a file in `wb` mode.

As you are a PHP developer, I would only use what you have to in python:

Option one:

Save to a file and pick it up with PHP

```
...
output = image
f=open ("someFileName.png", wb)
f.write(output[1])
f.close()
```

Then use `"someFileName.png"` with your PHP wrapper.

Option two:
call the python script form the PHP wrapper. Pass the image data to the wrapper as the exit code.

```
...
output = image
import sys
sys.exit(output[1])
```

Comment: I do apologize, but I'm a little bit confused. My goal is not to save the file but rather dump it to the browser with the correct content type. It's all part of a very large web application I'm working on. I have no experience with Python beyond basic automation. The output is being generated by a DLL which was originally programmed in C++. The Python API the authors made is simply a wrapper for this. The documentation is a little weak on this area, but it seems like the information I have is enough to decipher whats going on if I knew more about Python.

Comment: If I understand correctly, python is only used in part of your overall flow. Do you know how to display a PNG using any of the other tools at your disposal?

Comment: I'm almost entirely a PHP developer, though no PHP wrapper for their code exists at this time, and porting their library is beyond my capabilities. While I couldn't off hand find any previous examples, there were two ways of doing things. Either: (a) hard code it into your HTML as base64 encoded PNG

    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">

Or: <img src="moleculePNG.py" height="xx" width="xx"> etc... where moleculePNG.py uses session data to generate on the fly

Comment: Wrapping this particular part in PHP was a consideration, but I couldn't come up with a good way to do it and it wasn't necessary. The script itself is standalone and is to be called by the client's browser when requesting the image. I had originally thought of doing what you were suggesting with the array, but it doesn't work. I tried your first option, and while it does generate "someFileName.png", the file contains simply the character 'P'. This is where I was getting rather confused, because Python isn't handling it like an array I'm used to.